# Efficient reading from Kafka with Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I have an app, which gets data from Kafka and save it to the database. My code looks like this:

```scala
spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .options(options)
  .load()
  .writeStream
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(20000))
  .foreachBatch({ (batch: DataFrame, _: Long) =>
    val rowsCount = batch.count
    saveBatch(batch)
    println(s"Saved $rowsCount rows")
  })
  .start()
```

In Spark UI I look into the Structure Streaming tab and see, that process rate of my stream is 100K rows per second.
If I remove rows counting like this:

```scala
.foreachBatch({ (batch: DataFrame, _: Long) =>
    saveBatch(batch)
  })
  .start()
```

process rate becomes 50K per second.
As you can see, in first case I don't using caching, and when I calculating count of rows in batch and saving batch to database, I probably read data from Kafka twice (instead of second case, when reading is only one time)
I can't belive, that such trivial operation, like rows counting is leading to additional reading from kafka, is it any approaches, to get batch length without caching data?

Comment: It's not reading from Kafka twice. Spark is just iterating the same batch (in memory) twice... If you just want to save data from Kafka to a database, this is what Kafka Connect is for

Comment: I thought Spark should iterate data in memory only in case it was cached. If you reading file from hdfs and counting rows multiple times, you will reading it from disk every time

Comment: Kafka doesn't work that way, at least, it shouldn't with Spark since the consumed batch maintains a checkpoint to the last offset that was polled and it doesn't need to constantly seek backwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@OneCricketeer you right, Spark doesn't read from Kafka multiple times. I checked DAG scheme and there is only one "MicroBatchScan" stage in both cases. In addition I compared network utilization on Kafka hosts, and there isn't any differance too (output is the same).
It looks like "process rate" in Structure Streaming tab means exact count of processed rows, during batch processing, but it doesn't affect reading from Kafka